# Laravel Form Requests hasFile() not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel form request to validate a array of input group. I need to check files using a loop for a custom validation. But it shows this error.

```
Error
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::hasFile()
```

My HTML inputs (createUser.blade.php)

```
<input type="text"  name="users[0][name]">
<input type="number"  name="users[0][age]">
<input type="file"  name="users[0][profile_pic]">

<input type="text"  name="users[1][name]">
<input type="number"  name="users[1][age]">
<input type="file"  name="users[1][profile_pic]">
```

My Form Request (CreateUserFormRequest.php)

```
dd($this->request->hasFile('users');
```

Comment: What Laravel version?

Comment: Please show your controller, WHERE are you doing that `dd(...)` line? What your context, what class are you even in?

Comment: Laravel 7.2 version

Comment: This is before controller. In the Form Request.

Comment: Look at the [Laravel 7.x documentation of `FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html): There is a method `hasFile()`. If `$this->hasFile()` doesn't work, you are in the wrong class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `FormRequest` class if you want to check whether request has value or not then you can do like below

```
$this->has('users')
```

If you want to check request has file or not then

```
 $this->hasFile('logo')
```

also make sure input type is file

To check all data in request then

```
 $this->all()
```

**For files make sure input type is file**

```
<input type="file"  name="users[1][profile_pic]">
```

Also make sure  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Updated
<form method="POST" action="{{route("testing")}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
    <input type="number"  name="users[0][name]">
    <input type="number"  name="users[0][age]">
    <input type="file"  name="users[0][profile_pic]">

    <input type="number"  name="users[1][name]">
    <input type="number"  name="users[1][age]">
    <input type="file"  name="users[1][profile_pic]">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

and in Form request

```
 foreach ($this->users as $key=>$value){
            if($value['profile_pic']!=null){
                dump($value['profile_pic']);
            }
        }
```

If you are looking for file validation then you can do the following

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'users.*.profile_pic'=>'required|file'
        ];
    }
```

and in your view

```
   <input type="file"  name="users[0][profile_pic]">
    {{ $errors->first('users.0.profile_pic') }}

    <input type="file"  name="users[1][profile_pic]">
    {{ $errors->first('users.1.profile_pic') }}
```

Comment: $this->hasFile('logo'). this returns an error "Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::hasFile()" inside form request

Comment: sorry. It was by mistake. I edited it. Even though I add like that still it returns that undefined method error

Comment: `hasFile()` is not part of the Symfony [`ParameterBag`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php), it's part of the Laravel [`Request`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/Request.php#L143) object. Your context (`$this`) is different.

Comment: @camille.updated post not sure why you need to loop check hasfile in Formrequest.instead you can add array validation

Comment: Thanks. Now I can finally get the file in the FormRequest. I'm performing a custom validation function which is required to check whether the file exists along with some other parameter values.

Comment: very very important make sure enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag